# DataPipeline: Use only first 4 values from CSV in pipeline

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a CSV, which has a variable structure, which I only want to take the first 4 values from. The CSV stored in S3 has between 7 and 8 fields in it, and I would like to take just the first 4. I have attempted to use the following prepared statement:

`INSERT INTO locations (timestamp, item_id, latitude, longitude) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);`

However I am getting:

`Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4).`

Which I believe means that it is attempting to load in the other variables in the CSV. Is it possible to just take the first 4 values? Or otherwise deal with a variable length CSV?

Comment: @franklinsijo any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Use transformSql option. You didn't mention what you are loading into, from [redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html) docs :

> The SQL SELECT expression used to transform the input data. When you
>   copy data from DynamoDB or Amazon S3, AWS Data Pipeline creates a
>   table called staging and initially loads it in there. Data from this
>   table is used to update the target table. If the transformSql option
>   is specified, a second staging table is created from the specified SQL
>   statement. The data from this second staging table is then updated in
>   the final target table. transformSql must be run on the table named
>   staging and the output schema of transformSql must match the final
>   target table's schema.